# how to get data from mysql database from zoho creator

Tags: mysql, database

I need to fetch data from the MySQL database from the Zoho creator and I need to be able to update, create and delete the data in the database. I couldn't find any relevant document for this.

I tried to use invoke url function but it is for API only. I'm clueless.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.